# Connect to Wifi instead of creating Hotspot on boot

Tags: networking, wireless, hot-spot

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on my laptop. I have configured a wifi hotspot on it. Prior to this configuration, it used to connect to my wifi router by default on booting. Now, it just starts the wifi hotspot instead of connecting to Wifi AP.
Is there a default setting where I can mention the default behavior of connecting to wifi instead of creating a hotspot?

Answer (score 0):

Click the Network Manager icon and select 'Edit Connections.' Select your network and click 'Edit.' Under Mode, select 'Client.' Save and close.

[image]

Comment: Ok. So, for the Hotspot Connection I must select Mode as Client? And whenever I need to turn it into a hotspot, change it back to hotspot? Is that what you mean?

Comment: When you wish to connect to your router to access the internet, you want Client mode. To turn into a hotspot, select Hotspot mode.

Comment: nope. Not helping.

Comment: Meaning what? Do you mean that you switch to client mode, save and close but then it won't connect to the internet? Does it see available networks? What happens when you click on yours? Does it try to connect? Or...what?

Comment: See,  I have two networks available under the Wifi-networks. One is UbuntuHotspot and second one is NetgearRouter. On boot my laptop connects to UbuntuHotspot, which I dont want!  As you mentioned, I turned the mode of UbuntuHotspot into "Client". So it is no longer listed in the Networks Available as a HotSpot. I use Hotspot to just create a network of a few mobile devices and my laptop.

Comment: You still have helped me understand the result. You select 'Client' and then the UbuntuHotSpot is no longer available. So then you still see nad can click on NetgearRouter. Does it connect? Is your question actually that both Client and Hotspot work perfectly well as expected but you wish to default, on boot, to Client mode and to automatically connect?

Comment: YES! I never said that there is any problem. I just want to select the default out of Hotspot and my home router, which apparently should be the router. And I converted Hotspot config to "Client". Whenever I need the hotspot I convert the Mode back to Hotspot.